# Safari Favorites/Bookmark Icon not displaying

Tags: html, safari, favicon

This pertains to Safari Bookmark and Favorites Icons
No matter what I do, I cannot get my bookmark icon/favorites icon to appear. I've tried the following:

```
 <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
```

Waited for days, cleared my cache, and nothing. Then I added:

```
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://mywebsite.com/images/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://mywebsite.com/images/favicon-144x144.png" sizes="144x144">
```

And it still doesn't work. I also added an apple-touch-icon.png in my root directory, and this works, but only for adding my website to the homescreen. For bookmarks and favorites, it still shows just the first letter of my website.

I've researched everywhere and nothing seems to work, have things changed? Help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most commonly accepted way is to have a `favicon.ico` file in your site's root directory. You can generate a favicon file [here](https://realfavicongenerator.net/).

To set icons explicitly you can look [here](https://github.com/joshbuchea/HEAD#favicons), but this is complementary.

Comment: does it have to be .ico? And does the size matter?

Comment: Updated the answer with a link to a favicon generator website

Comment: I checked it out thanks. Does it take time for everything to appear? I followed all the instructions, cleared my cache and it still won't show up

Comment: Nevermind, I had to do some more thorough cache clearing for it to finally appear. Thank you so much for the link!

Comment: Great to hear! Cheers 

Comment: Tell us what you did to get it to work! Did you just go into Settings and "Clear History & Website Data"? Did you do more?

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 11.4 you have to close the Safari app first and then clear the cached data.